# Regex - how to match everything except a particular pattern

Tags: regex, findstr

How do I write a regex to match any string that doesn't meet a particular pattern? I'm faced with a situation where I have to match an (A and ~B) pattern.

Comment: PCRE would be best for this: see [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when… / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174). I removed `findstr` tag since all answers here are not valid for the tag.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You could use a look-ahead assertion:

```
(?!999)\d{3}
```

This example matches three digits other than `999`.

---

But if you happen not to have a regular expression implementation with this feature (see [Comparison of Regular Expression Flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines)), you probably have to build a regular expression with the basic features on your own.

A compatible regular expression with basic syntax only would be:

```
[0-8]\d\d|\d[0-8]\d|\d\d[0-8]
```

This does also match any three digits sequence that is not `999`.

Comment: Look-ahead is not standard regular expression syntax, it is a Perl extension, it will only work in Perl, PCRE (Perl-Compatible RegEx) or other non-standard implementations

Comment: It may not be standard, but don't most modern languages support it? What language *doesn't* support look-aheads these days?

Comment: That’s true. But most regex flavors support this feature (see <http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html>).

Comment: Turns out that the windows findstr function only supports pure DFA-style regex anyway, so I need to just do it all differently.  You still get the answer, though.

Comment: i think the last regex would also not match 009, 019... etc

Comment: Standard Lex for C does not use PCREs :-(

Answer (score 32):

If you want to match a word A in a string and not to match a word B. For example:
If you have a text:

```
1. I have a two pets - dog and a cat
2. I have a pet - dog
```

If you want to search for lines of text that **HAVE a dog** for a pet and **DOESN'T have cat** you can use this regular expression:

```
^(?=.*?\bdog\b)((?!cat).)*$
```

It will find only second line:

```
2. I have a pet - dog
```

Comment: He failed mention it in the question, but the OP is actually using the DOS `findstr` command.  It affords only a tiny subset of the capabilities you expect to find in a regex tool; lookahead is not among them.  (I just added the [tag:findstr] tag myself.)

Comment: hm, yes, I found now in one of his comments on the posts. I saw Regex in the title. Anyways, if somebody finds this post when searching for the same for regular expression, like I did, maybe it could be helpful to someone :) thanks for comments

Answer (score 15):

Match against the pattern and use the host language to invert the boolean result of the match. This will be much more legible and maintainable.

Comment: Then I just end up with (~A or B) instead of (A and ~B).  It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Pseudo-code:

String toTest;
if (toTest.matches(A) AND !toTest.matches(B)) { ... }

Comment: I should have been more clear - the pieces are not fully independent.  If A matches part of the string, then we care if ~B matches the rest of it (but not necessarily the whole thing).  This was for the windows command-line findstr function, which i found is restricted to true regexs, so moot point.

Answer (score 8):

notnot, resurrecting this ancient question because it had a simple solution that wasn't mentioned. (Found your question while doing some research for a [regex bounty quest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).)

> I'm faced with a situation where I have to match an (A and ~B)
>   pattern.

The basic regex for this is frighteningly simple: `B|(A)`

You just ignore the overall matches and examine the Group 1 captures, which will contain A.

An example (with all the disclaimers about parsing html in regex): A is digits, B is digits within `<a tag`

The regex: `<a.*?<\/a>|(\d+)`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uS4iZ7) (look at Group 1 in the lower right pane)

**Reference**

[How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

[How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: This sounds too good to be true! Unfortunately, this solution is not universal and it fails in Emacs, even after replacing `\d` with `[[:digit:]]`. [The first reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between) mentions it is specific to Perl and PHP: "There is a variation using syntax specific to Perl and PHP that accomplishes the same."

Answer (score 4):

The complement of a regular language is also a regular language, but to construct it you have to build the [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata) for the regular language, and make any valid state change into an error. See [this](http://nitsan.org/~maratb/cs164/lminus.html) for an example. What the page doesn't say is that it converted `/(ac|bd)/` into `/(a[^c]?|b[^d]?|[^ab])/`. The conversion from a DFA back to a regular expression is not trivial. It is easier if you can use the regular expression unchanged and change the semantics in code, like suggested before.

Comment: If I were dealing with actual regex's then this would all be moot.  Regex now seems to refer to the nebulous CSG-ish (?) space of pattern matching that most langauges support.  Since I need to match (A and ~B), there's no way to remove the negation and still do it all in one step.

Comment: Lookahead, as described above, would have done it if findstr did anything beyond true DFA regexs.  The whole thing is sort of odd and I don't know why I have to do this command-line (batch now) style.  It's just another example of my hands being tied.

Comment: @notnot: You are using findstr from Windows? Then you just need /v. Like:
findstr A inputfile | findstr /v B > outputfile.txt
The first matches all lines with A, the second matches all lines that doesn't have B.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually exactly what I needed.  I didn't ask the question that way, though, so I still giving the answer to Gumbo for the more generalized answer.

Answer (score 2):

pattern - re

```
str.split(/re/g)
```

will return everything except the pattern.

Test [here](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm)

Comment: You probably want to mention that you need to join then again.

Comment: A similar approach is using `replace`

`str.replace(/re/g, '')`, then there's no need to rejoin them.

also if you throw in a nice trailing \s? like `str.replace(/\re\s?/g, '')` then you get rid of any duplicate spaces you would have from something being replaced in the middle of a string

Answer (score 0):

```
(B)|(A)
```

then use what group 2 captures...

Comment: He needs to *capture* not B, he aim is not to just ignore all the B patterns.

Answer (score 0):

My answer here might solve your problem as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27967674/543814

- Instead of Replace, you would use Match.
- Instead of group `$1`, you would read group `$2`.
- Group `$2` was made non-capturing there, which you would avoid.

Example:

`Regex.Match("50% of 50% is 25%", "(\d+\%)|(.+?)");`

The first capturing group specifies the pattern that you wish to avoid. The last capturing group captures everything else. Simply read out that group, `$2`.