# How to formulate this select statement in KRL?

Tags: regex, krl

I'm trying to write a `select` statement that will run on `www.google.com/blahblahblah` but not `www.google.com/readerblahblahblah`

Please help. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. What does your question mean? What are you trying to accomplish? And using what language/technology?

Comment: @Cody, The language is KRL (hence the tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to literally match the "blahblahblah" you can do something like this:

```
select when pageview "www\.google\.com/blahblahblah"
```

This will not match "readerblahblahblah". If, however, you mean that you want to match everything on google.com except for "/reader", you'll need something like this:

```
select when pageview "www\.google\.com/(?!reader)(.*)" setting (matched)
```

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern/611897#611897) for more details.