# A pattern that matches all except starting with a word

Tags: java, regex

How can I set a regex pattern which matches **all words but** the strings which starts with

1. /word
2. /word/
3. /word/ following by anything else.

I think the pattern starts with  \A but I don'0t know how to tell that should not follow a word

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this kind of negate regex and replace word by your word.

```
^((?!word).)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex:

```
^(?!\\/word).*$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/rbjPapICq5)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) feature offered by regular expressions. Also, a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern). Also, posting your question in terms of a concrete sample problem might help you get a few working sample snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a string comparison will be clearer and faster.

```
if (text.startsWith("word")) {
   // text is OK
} else {
   // not OK
}
```

Comment: it's a regex used in xml

Comment: I assumed it was a Java question. ;)