# Regex: how to stop match a url if it fits one pattern

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a url rewrite regex to find strings having dash between each slash pair, for example,

```
/aaa-bb/cc/dd-ee-ff/gg
```

should match `aaa-bb` and `dd-ee-ff`. I need it to match nothing if url contains `/test/`, so for url `/aaa-bb/cc/test/dd-ee-ff/gg`, it should match nothing. I have written a regex

```
/\w+-(\w+(?!\.)-?)+
```

it will find all strings contains `-`, but I can't add the pattern for the `/test/` part.

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to put those `\w`s into a character class.

Comment: Try using the pipe `|` operator. More info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, regex cannot maintain a state, and for that reason you should separate what you're doing into two separate checks, nesting the dash check within the test check.

```
if(!hasTest) {
  //check for dashes
}
```

Comment: It appears that the OP is using `mod_rewrite`, so this is not a viable workaround.

Comment: oh sorry, I do use mod_rewrite for tomcat :)

Comment: +1. With mod_rewrite, this check can be expressed using [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.5/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Answer (score 1):

Immediately preceding your RewriteRule that contains your regex, add a rewrite condition to exclude urls that contain the substring `/test/` anywhere in it. That RewriteCond would look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/
RewriteRule /\w+-(\w+(?!\.)-?)+ /some_place_else.html?parameters=$1
```