# Regular expression matching everything that does not contain a phrase

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Seemed like a trivial task to me but a failed to accomplish this in the past one hour.

The regular expression should match every word that does not contain the phrase 'exclude phrase'.

For instance:
Match:
'ok string'
'some phrasOk because thre is no e in phrase'
etc...

Not match:
'exclude phrase'
'Some prefix exclude phrase'
'exclude phrase some suffix'
etc...

Comment: probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 2):

If you have a phrase:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

The regex to find all words, but not 'sit' and 'adipiscing' will be:

> \b(?(?=sit|adipiscing)^\w+|\w+)\b

In php:

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/\b(?(?=sit|adipiscing)^\w+|\w+)\b/i", $text,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be a regex `^((?!phrase).)*$`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to solve this : regex for matching (trivial) then reverse condition.

Example in python:

```
>>> not(re.search ('exclude phrase','Some prefix exclude phrase'))
False
>>> not(re.search ('exclude phrase','exclude phrase some suffix'))
False
>>> not(re.search ('exclude phrase','ok string'))
True
```

Comment: Thanks for he answer, Bruce. I figure it out that with a programing language it is easy to accomplish. But this is not working for me. I need a pure Regex to acomplish the reverse check.