# Javascript Regular Expressions - how to NOT match a substring between < and >

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using this regular expression:

```
var regex = /\<.*?.\>/g
```

to match with this string:

```
var str = 'This <is> a string to <use> to test the <regular> expression'
```

using a simple match:

```
str.match(regex)
```

and, as expected, I get:

```
["<is>", "<use>", "<regular>"]
```

(But without the backslashes, sorry for any potential confusion)

How can I get the reverse result?  i.e. what regular expression do I need that does not return those items contained between `<` and `>`?

I tried `/(^\<.*?\>)/g` and various other similar combos including square brackets and stuff.  I've got loads of cool results, just nothing that is quite what I want.

Where I'm going with this:  Basically I want to search and replace occurences of substrings but I want to exclude some of the search space, probably using < and >.  I don't really want a destructive method as I don't want to break apart strings, change them, and worry about reconstructing them.

Of course I could do this 'manually' by searching through the string but I figured regular expressions should be able to handle this rather well.  Alas, my knowledge is not where it needs to be!!

Comment: You mean it returns `["<is>", "<use>", "<regular>"]`  ? By the way, no need to escape < and >

Comment: Ta, oh yeah, doh!  And yup, that is what I mean!  Couldn't get the formatting right

Comment: @MattStyles, I know you already picked an answer but check out my solution. Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: @cbayram Thanks for the input, that looks like a great solution as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do custom replacement of everything outside of the tags, and to strip the tags from the tagged parts http://jsfiddle.net/tcATT/

```
var string = 'This <is> a string to <use> to test the <regular> expression';
// The regular expression matches everything, but each val is either a
// tagged value (<is> <regular>), or the text you actually want to replace
// you need to decide that in the replacer function
console.log(str.replace( /[^<>]+|<.*?>/g, function(val){
    if(val.charAt(0) == '<' && val.charAt(val.length - 1) == '>') {
      // Just strip the < and > from the ends
      return val.slice(1,-1);
    } else {
      // Do whatever you want with val here, I'm upcasing for simplicity
      return val.toUpperCase(); 
    }
} ));​
// outputs: "THIS is A STRING TO use TO TEST THE regular EXPRESSION"
```

To generalize it, you could use

```
function replaceOutsideTags(str, replacer) {
    return str.replace( /[^<>]+|<.*?>/g, function(val){
        if(val.charAt(0) == '<' && val.charAt(val.length - 1) == '>') {
          // Just strip the < and > from the ends
          return val.slice(1,-1);
        } else {
          // Let the caller decide how to replace the parts that need replacing
          return replacer(val); 
        }
    })
}
// And call it like
console.log(
    replaceOutsideTags( str, function(val){
        return val.toUpperCase();
    })
);
```

Comment: That looks brilliant!  I'll take some proper time to understand how it works tomorrow!  I'm almost entirely certain that will solve the real problem I'm working on.  Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to apply some custom processing to a string except parts that are *protected* (enclosed in with `<` and `>`)? If, this is the case you could do it like this:

```
// The function that processes unprotected parts
function process(s) {
    // an example could be transforming whole part to uppercase:
    return s.toUpperCase();
}

// The function that splits string into chunks and applies processing
// to unprotected parts
function applyProcessing (s) {
    var a = s.split(/<|>/),
        out = '';

    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        out += i%2
                ? a[i]
                : process(a[i]);

    return out;
}

// now we just call the applyProcessing()
var str1 = 'This <is> a string to <use> to test the <regular> expression';
console.log(applyProcessing(str1));
// This outputs:
// "THIS is A STRING TO use TO TEST THE regular EXPRESSION"

// and another string:
var str2 = '<do not process this part!> The <rest> of the a <string>.';
console.log(applyProcessing(str2));
// This outputs:
// "do not process this part! THE rest OF THE A string."
```

This is basically it. It returns the whole string with the unprotected parts processed.

Please note that the splitting will not work correctly if the angle brackets (`<` and `>`) are not balanced.

There are various places that could be improved but I'll leave that as an excersize to the reader. ;p

Comment: I'll all over exercises!  Thanks dude!

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect application for passing a regex argument to the core `String.split()` method:

```js
var results = str.split(/<[^<>]*>/);
```

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

Using the variables you've already created, try using `replace`. It's non-destructive, too.

```
str.replace(regex, '');
--> "This  a string to  to test the  expression"
```

Comment: How do you get the matched stuff back after the OP replaces what they need (outside of the tags) though? The OP wants to keep it

Comment: Thanks, I got to that stage but what I really want to do is replace 'test' with 'TADA' in that string but still have the stuff in <> included.  I could just search for 'test' of course, but it might be contained in < and > so would still get replaced.  Basically I want to replace 'test' everywhere that IS NOT within < >

Comment: @MattStyles Gotcha. To solve the problem you just described, try `str.replace(/([^<])test([^<])/g, '$1TADA$2');` There's probably a better way, however...

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of using $1 etc in some way.  That method works nice but I tested it with this string 'str = "This <is> a test that is <going to test whether> this regex is the right one" 'and it, unfortunately, changes the 'test' within < > so I end up with ""This <is> a TADA that is <going to TADA whether> this regex is the right one"

Answer (score 1):

```
/\b[^<\W]\w*(?!>)\b/g
```

This works, test it out:

```
var str = 'This <is> a string to <use> to test the <regular> expression.';
var regex = /\<.*?.>/g;
console.dir(str.match(regex));
var regex2 = /\b[^<\W]\w*(?!>)\b/g;
console.dir(str.match(regex2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah, okay, sorry - I misunderstood your question. This is a difficult problem to solve with pure regular expressions in javascript, because javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, and usually I think I would use lookaheads and lookbehinds to solve this. A (sort of contrived) way of doing it would be something like this:

```
str.replace(/((?:<[^>]+>)?)([^<]*)/g, function (m, sep, s) { return sep + s.replace('test', 'FOO'); })

// --> "This <is> a string to <use> to FOO the <regular> expression"
```

This also works on strings like `"This test <is> a string to <use> to test the <regular> expression"`, and if you use `/test/g` instead of `'test'` in the replacer function, it will also turn

```
"This test <is> a string to <use> to test the test <regular> expression"
```

into

```
"This FOO <is> a string to <use> to FOO the FOO <regular> expression"
```

**UPDATE**

And something like this would also strip the <> characters:

```
str.replace(/((?:<[^>]+>)?)([^<]*)/g, function (m, sep, s) { return sep.replace(/[<>]/g, '') + s.replace(/test/g, 'FOO'); })

"This test <is> a string to <use> to test the test <regular> expression"
--> "This FOO is a string to use to FOO the FOO regular expression"
```

Comment: How is this any different than what depot posted? How's the OP supposed to get the `["<is>", "<use>", "<regular>"]` back into the string. This gets a -1 because it duplicated the problem of an existing answer, prove me wrong and you get the upvote

Comment: Okay, sorry, I deserved that -1. I guess I didn't understand the questing before read the comments left at depot's answer. I have updated my answer to something better :-)

Comment: Ah, okay, and it also needs to strip the separator characters :-)

Comment: I think my answer is doing what the OP asked for, what do you think?

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
\b\w+\b(?!>)
```

UPDATE

To support spaces inside brackets try this one. It's not pure regex.match, but it works and it's much simpler that the answer above:

```
alert('This <is> a string to <use use> to test the <regular> expression'.split(/\s*<.+?>\s*/).join(' '));
```

Comment: What? Please explain,  I can't make sense of it, tempted to vote down

Comment: I just get <regular> back, which makes sense to me.  Can't get it to help me though, what am I missing?

Comment: It's just a look-ahead assertion. We catch all content in < > except strings listed after ?! and separated by pipe | .  Look [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern) for additional reference

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstood the question. I thought you'd like to get all <blablabla> entries except few pre-defined. Changed.

Comment: That's brilliant!  However, when I test with a complex str such as ""This <is> a test that is <going to test whether> this regex is the test right one" then it struggles with the space between the middle < > .  Do I need to add a \s somewhere?

Comment: Oh. Using spaces makes the regexp much more complicated. I even not sure that I can do this using js regexp. With perl - np =)

Comment: Added one more solution. Try it!

Comment: That works great for the simple example but the splitting and joining deforms the original string and I eventually need to run another replace, but only on the bits not in the <> so I can't have any other deformation of the string. A pain! Looks like the solutions above will work though but thanks very much for taking the time to answer, it's all good to look at to learn more about regex