# Regex for subdomain that follows anysubdomain.domain

Tags: regex

I need a regex for a subdomain but I can't seem to find one and am useless at writing them.

I need a regex to match:

> sub1.mydomain.com 
>   sub1.mydomain.local

But not to match:

> www.mydomain.com 
>   www.mydomain.local

Or:

> [any protocol]//[anysubdomain except www].mydomain.[anysuffix]

Anyone care to take a go at this one?

Update (what I have).

Yes I have just now:

```
^(?!.*www)[a-z]*(.)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)\.([A-Za-z]*)(.*)$
```

However I need "mydomain.com" to not match.

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern I think you'll find the answer you're looking for there.

Comment: You will find that my updated regex matches your updated need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex works:

```
(\w+://)?(?!www)(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)
```

so, in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var match = Regex.Match("http://sub.blah.com", @"(\w+://)?(?!www)(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)");
    foreach (var g in match.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(g);
    }
}
```

prints

```
http://sub.blah.com
http://
sub
blah
com
```

And if you replace `"http://sub.blah.com"` by `"http://www.blah.com"` or `"www.blah.com"` or `"blah.com"`, the program prints nothing (it doesn't find a match). `"sub.blah.com"` matches however.

Comment: Sorry but when testing this with IsMatch("sd.domain.local") is does not product a match when it should

Comment: well, you mentioned you wanted the protocol.

Comment: @Paul If the protocol is optional, you can you `(\w+://)(?!www)(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)` instead.