# Regex to catch a string without () in 3 patterns like abc(ef) ,(ef)abc and (ef)abc(gh)

Tags: regex

I have tested this Regex
  `(?<=\))(.+?)(?=\()|(?<=\))(.+?)\b|(.+?)(?=\()`

but it doesn't work for strings like this pattern `(ef)abc(gh)`.

I got a result like this `"(ef)abc"`.

But these 3 regexes    `(?<=\))(.+?)(?=\()` ,   `(?<=\))(.+?)\b`,   `(.+?)(?=\()`
 do work separately for `"(ef)abc(gh)"`, `"(ef)abc"` ,`"abc(ef)"`  .

can anyone tell me where the problem is or how can I get the expected result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern?rq=1

Comment: Please provide a clear example of your intended output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to match the text from between the elements in parenthesis, try this:

```
^(?:\(\w*\))?([\w]*)(?:\(\w*\))?$

^            - beginning of string
(?:\(\w*\))? - non-capturing group, match 0 or more alphabetic letters within parens, all optional
([\w]*)      - capturing group, match 0 or more alphabetic letters
(?:\(\w*\))? - non-capturing group, match 0 or more alphabetic letters within parens, all optional
$            - end of string
```

You haven't specified what language you might be using, but here is an example in Python:

```
>>> import re

>>> string = "(ef)abc(gh)"
>>> string2 = "(ef)abc"
>>> string3 = "abc(gh)"

>>> p = re.compile(r'^(?:\(\w*\))?([\w]*)(?:\(\w*\))?$')

>>> m = re.search(p, string)
>>> m2 = re.search(p, string2)
>>> m3 = re.search(p, string3)

>>> print m.groups()[0]
'abc'
>>> print m2.groups()[0]
'abc'
>>> print m3.groups()[0]
'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\([^)]+\)|([^()\n]+)
```

Try this.Just grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/6

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `(.+?)(?=\()` matches "(ef)abc" in "(ef)abc(gh)".

The easiest solution to this problem is be more explicit about what you are looking for.  In this case by exchanging "any character" `.`, with "any character that is not a parenthesis" `[^\(\)]`.

```
(?<=\))([^\(\)]+?)(?=\()|(?<=\))([^\(\)]+?)\b|([^\(\)]+?)(?=\()
```

A cleaner regexp would be

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\)))([^\(\)]+)(?:(?=\()|(?=$))
```