# Regex replace everything except a particular pattern

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm looking to extract:

`50%`

From a string that will have more or less this format:

`The 50% is in here somewhere.`

I'd also like to extract:

`50%50%25%`

From a string like this:

`50% of 50% is 25%`

`Regex.Match()` seems the obvious contender. However, this involves checking if any matches were found (e.g. `match.Success`), extracting the results from a particular index in the array, and/or the risk of addressing an out-of-bounds index.

Regex replace is generally simpler to apply. A single line does the job, including returning the resulting string. This is true for so many languages.

`result = Regex.Replace(input, stuffWeDontLike, "")`

Basically, I am looking for a **regex filter** - instead of entering the pattern to *replace*, I want to enter the pattern to *retrieve*.

`percentages = Regex.Filter("50% of 50% is 25%", "[0-9]+\%")`

Could we form a regex and invert the result, as if it were a selection? That would allow the use of regex replace. However, I could not find a way to easily invert a regex.

How can we achieve the desired result (or similar; a join or so seems acceptable) with very short and simple syntax, similar to regex replace?

Comment: So, do you wish to REPLACE or EXTRACT in the end? Extraction is done by using groups (parenthesis) and checking your Regex Matches.Groups

Comment: I want to extract, but as a one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Matches` and concatenate each matches result. Just pick one you like the most.

```
//Sadly, we can't extend the Regex class
public class RegExp
{
    //usage : RegExp.Filter("50% of 50% is 25%", @"[0-9]+\%")
    public static string Filter(string input, string pattern)
    {
        return Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>()
            .Aggregate(string.Empty, (a,m) => a += m.Value);
    }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    //usage : "50% of 50% is 25%".Filter(@"[0-9]+\%")
    public static string Filter(this string input, string pattern)
    {
        return Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>()
            .Aggregate(string.Empty, (a,m) => a += m.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: One-liners. Just what I was hoping for! In the context of multiple developers, a snippet was more suitable anyway. I now insert `Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Aggregate("", (s, m) => s + m.Value);` This solution communicates intent better than my replace abuse, while still being very concise.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand your reasoning why you want to use replace.  Why go that way in the first place?  There are methods in the `Regex` class that allow you to precisely get all the desired matches.  Your roundabout way at getting to your solution I find is pointless.

Just use `Matches()` to collect the matches.  You could then join them into the string that you wanted.

```
var str = "50% of 50% is 25%";
var re = new Regex(@"\d+%");
var ms = re.Matches(str);
var values = ms.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
var joined = String.Join("", values); // "50%50%25%"
```

Comment: I collapsed this into `String.Join("", Regex.Matches(str, @"[0-9]+\%").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));` Preferred the solution using `Aggregate()` in the end, because it maintains the logical reading order even on a single line.

Comment: Btw, `[0-9]` cannot be freely replaced by `\d`, because the latter also matches things like Arabic numerals. I used `[0-9]` on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use regex replace as follows:

`Regex.Replace("50% of 50% is 25%", "(\d+\%)|(?:.+?)", "$1");`

Output:

`50%50%25%`

As a general approach:

`Regex.Replace(input, (pattern)|(?:.+?), "$1");`

This finds anything that matches either of the following:

- The pattern. Captured as `$1`. This is what we want to keep.
- Any character, any number of times, but non-greedy. This finds anything that is *not* captured by the first group. `?:` because we don't need to capture this group.

As MSDN states: "`$1` replaces the entire match with the first captured subexpression." (That is, all matches for that substring, concatenated.)

Effectively, this is the described *regex filter*.

Comment: I deleted my other comment. But.... what would be wrong with `(pattern)|.` instead of `(pattern)|(?:.+?)` and then still using `$1` in the replace section?

Comment: I believe that should work. I had the hunch that a single `.+?` would be faster than repeating `.` to clear out chunks of uninteresting characters at a time, but I might very well be mistaken.