# Find an item in the text with exceptions[Regular Expression]

Tags: regex

Please help create a regular expression that would be allocated "|" character everywhere except parentheses.

```
example|example (example(example))|example|example|example(example|example|example(example|example))|example
```

After making the selection should have 5 characters "|" are out of the equation. I want to note that the contents within the brackets should remain unchanged including the "|" character within them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - how to match everything except a particular pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern)

Comment: I read that article that you sent, but I regret not describe the solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to match pipes that are outside any set of parentheses, with nested sets, here's the pattern to achieve what you want:

**Regex:**

```
(?x)                     # Allow comments in regex (ignore whitespace)
(?:                      # Repeat *
    [^(|)]*+             #  Match every char except ( ) or |
    (                    #  1. Group 1
        \(               #    Opening paren
        (?:              #    chars inside:
            [^()]++      #     a. everything inside parens except nested parens
          |              #      or
            (?1)         #     b. nested parens (recurse group 1)
        )                #
        \)               #   Until closing paren.
    )?+                  #   (end of group 1)
)*+                      #
\K                       #  Keep text out of match
\|                       #  Match a pipe
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQ7gI4/3)</kbd>

**One-liner:**

```
(?:[^(|)]*+(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))\))?+)*+\K\|
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQ7gI4/4)</kbd>

---

This pattern uses some advanced features:

- [Possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)
- [Recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)
- [Resetting the match start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)