# Ignoring </span> tag and placing all closing tags before span opening tag in php

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-replace

My code in php is:

```
while(preg_match('%(<span style="color: green;">)(?:\s+)?(</.*?>)%i', $result2)==1){
    $result2 = preg_replace('%(<span style="color: green;">)(?:\s+)?(</.*?>)%i', '$2 $1', $result2);
}
```

Right now I have an input such as:

```
 <span style="color: green;"></p></i>
```

and what my code does is that whenever any tag is closing after this span green tag, they are placed before span. So the output for the above input would be:

```
 </p></i><span style="color: green;">
```

I want that if there is any span tag closing after this span green tag, that should be ignored and all other closing tags should be placed first..
Example Input:

```
<span style="color: green;"></p></span></i>
```

Output:

```
 </p></i><span style="color: green;"></span>
```

Can anybody help me out in making this change?

Answer (score 1):

In general for some regex implementations you can use look-ahead mechanism, which would look like `(?!</span>)(</.*?>)` instead of just `(</.*?>)` in your match/replace pattern.

Otherwise, please check [Regex - how to match everything except a particular pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern) as it solves the general problem for both standard and non-standard implementations.

You can also rely a bit less on regex, and just check in your loop if the tag you found matches , if so break the loop (if I understand your idea correctly).

Edit: if you want to keep moving the tags after the span is closed, you can just add  to accepted 'content', like:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8177a9afbdd5ac7c1660679d9cb362a9b48c29a4
you would probably like to accept something more in the span content, like `\w+` (your code is loosing it totally) and if you want many span closing tags you need to make it more generic too, but the idea behind it is the same

Comment: I made the change according to your comment but it does not work. Here is my edit: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b32fa631952cf6554623a2a536f13a27d92f12ef

Comment: well, youre not very specific in how do you want to handle closing span tags, for me it was obvious you want to stop at the first </span> if not, you can check the updated answer

Comment: I want: Example:  input: <span style="color: green;"></p></span></i> Output: </p></i><span style="color: green;"></span>

Comment: so the code in sandbox I posted will do exactly that if you run it in loop

Comment: In loop it is bringing span too infront. Can you please see it? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c7013f5aeabb9365424f52d56cfde37244e18d9     Let me know if I have made any mistake

Comment: it's all fine except that there is one iteration too much, just check if the group you are trying to move in front is not </span> and if so, break. You can also think about just finding all tags, and rewriting the code without using regex (<span style...>)(</.*>) -> find all of group 2, and except for those matching </span> put in a list, and then create a string as (in psudocode) result = $2.join(tags, '') + $1

Comment: I can't break it on </span> I need to check further too

Comment: when you get </span> all the other tags are already moved. Didn't you notice?