# regex: How to match these words except those words?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I want to match some words in regex except some others:

ex: all words that contains straat, laan, baan

```
(straat|laan|baan)
```

But not

```
(overslaan|bestraat|rubaan)
```

ex: mystraat bolaan overslaan boobaan rubaan

should match

mystraat bolaan boobaan

Comment: This has been answered a number of times. You can use look-ahead assertions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern

Comment: If you want to match whole words, not just parts, something like this should work: https://regex101.com/r/LLE1XQ/2

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit complex but can be done with a negative lookbehind.

Try something like this:

```
$goodString = "coolbaan";
$badString = "rubaan";

$stringToTest = $goodString;

$regexPattern = '/(.*?)((?<!overs|ru|be)(straat|laan|baan))/';

preg_match($regexPattern, $stringToTest, $matches);
if ($matches) {
  // $matches[1] will be the prefix - e.g. ru
  // $matches[2] will be the suffix e.g. baan
  // $result will be 'rubaan'
  $result = "{$matches[1]}{$matches[2]}";
} else {
  $result = 'No Match!';
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score -2):

just add ^ in front of your regex and $ to end check below code:

```
/^[straat|laan|baan]$/
```